# How to find the ids used by current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a quiz and i displayed the items in one per page.. i want the values of question id that is visited by the current user . in this code i give next and it render the question i want the visited question id by current user

```
def next
@user = current_user
@student = Student.find_by_admission_no(@user.username)
@exam_group = ExamGroup.find_by_id(params[:exam_group_id])
@answer = Answer.new(params[:ans])
@answer.answer = params[:answer]
@answer.exam_group_id = @exam_group.id
@answer.user_id = @user.id
passed_question = params[:passed_question]
@answer.questions_id = passed_question
next_question = params[:next_question]
@question = Question.find_by_id(passed_question)
@module = Question.find_by_sql ["SELECT student_additional_field_id FROM questions WHERE id=#{passed_question}"]
student_additional_field_id = @module[0].student_additional_field_id
@questions = Question.find(:all, :conditions => [' exam_group_id=? && student_additional_field_id=? ',@exam_group,student_additional_field_id], :offset => @ans)

@ques = []
@questions.shuffle.each do |a|
  @ques.push a.id unless a.id.nil?
end
a = @ques[0]
session[:ques_id] = a
@answer.modules_id = student_additional_field_id
  if params[:answer] == @question.is_answer
    @answer.marks = 1
  else
    @answer.marks = 0
  end

if @answer.save
  @ans = Question.find_by_id(a, :conditions => [' id not in (?) && exam_group_id=?',answered, @exam_group])
  unless @ans.nil?
    render(:update) do |page|
      page.replace_html 'main', :partial => 'ans', :object => @ans
    end
  else
    render(:update) do |page|
      page.replace_html 'main', :partial => 'ans2'
    end
  end
end
end
```

Comment: [Spaghetti Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) >.<

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem is to do with [Rails model associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html):

> Why do we need associations between models? Because they make common
>   operations simpler and easier in your code. For example, consider a
>   simple Rails application that includes a model for customers and a
>   model for orders. Each customer can have many orders

---

**ActiveRecord Associations**

ActiveRecord associations allow you to define a `primary_key` (typically an ID), which you can then reference on other tables through a `foreign_key`. The foreign key is typically a table column which will be called something like `user_id`, or another type of ID

You can associate your models using these functions:

> - belongs_to
> - has_one
> - has_many
> - has_many :through
> - has_one :through
> - has_and_belongs_to_many

To answer your question, you're obviously getting the `current_user ID` okay - so if you managed to get the relations set up correctly, you could literally call the data in this way:

```
@user = User.find(current_user.id)
@exam_group = @user.exams_groups
```

I would go through your code & put more info into it.... but I think you need to learn about ActiveRecord associations first